# How to map CTRL+A, CTRL+E to function as Home, End system-wide?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hotkeys, key-binding, ubuntu-unity

Is there a way to map CTRL+A and CTRL+E to work **system-wide** as move to beginning of line, and move to end of line correspondingly?

I.e. I would like these shortcuts to seamlessly work in any app, not only in the terminal (i.e. as in OSX).

My main system is Ubuntu with the Unity desktop, but it would be good to have a universal solution which would be desktop-agnostic, or at least be supported in Gnome, XFCE and LXDE.

Comment: Ctrl-A is also used by `screen`, which I use (unless `tmux` is available). So you have to type Ctrl-A twice to get one. Isn't a mouse click faster to get to the wanted position.

Comment: xmodmap won't do what was asked (and the suggested link does not answer this particular question).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: `xmodmap` cannot do key combinations, it can only be used to map single keys. @ott: no, the mouse requires looking at the screen and pointing in the right place which is extra strain both for eyes and fingers.

Comment: Assuming that you are using terminal window, look at the stty utility.

Comment: @fpmurphy1: in the terminal CTRL+A and CTRL+E already work as Home/End, assuming the default shell (bash) is used.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your requirements.   No, there is no system-wide way to do what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) might seem to provide an answer, but it does not, because the *keycodes* it manipulates are existing keys on the keyboard, not *modified* keys.  A <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> is a modified key.

`xmodmap` can only reassign existing keycodes or (their names) keysyms, as listed in its manual page:

> **`keycode`** *NUMBER* = *KEYSYMNAME* ...
>   **`keycode`** **`any`** = *KEYSYMNAME* ...
>   **`keysym`** *KEYSYMNAME* = *KEYSYMNAME* ...

To see the keycodes that `xmodmap` knows about, run

```
xmodmap -pk
```

which shows something like this (shortened for clarity):

```
There are 4 KeySyms per KeyCode; KeyCodes range from 8 to 255.

    KeyCode Keysym (Keysym) ...
    Value   Value   (Name)  ...

      8     0x0061 (a)      0x0041 (A)      0x00e5 (aring)  0x00c5 (Aring)  
      9     0x0073 (s)      0x0053 (S)      0x00df (ssharp) 0x00cd (Iacute) 
     10     0x0064 (d)      0x0044 (D)      0x08ef (partialderivative)      0x00ce (Icircumflex)    
     11     0x0066 (f)      0x0046 (F)      0x08f6 (function)       0x00cf (Idiaeresis)     
     12     0x0068 (h)      0x0048 (H)      0x01ff (abovedot)       0x00d3 (Oacute) 
     13     0x0067 (g)      0x0047 (G)      0x00a9 (copyright)      0x01bd (doubleacute)    
     14     0x007a (z)      0x005a (Z)      0x07d9 (Greek_OMEGA)    0x00b8 (cedilla)
     ...
```

`xev` shows what actually happens:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    root 0x111, subw 0xc00002, time 2209364614, (27,43), root:(47,86),
    state 0x4, keycode 8 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (01) "^A"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (01) "^A"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    root 0x111, subw 0xc00002, time 2209364773, (27,43), root:(47,86),
    state 0x4, keycode 8 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (01) "^A"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The control modifier is the `0x4` in the state; the `XLookupString` (one of several related functions for combining key events) transforms the *keysym* for "a" into `^A` (control/A).

Because there is no keysym for any of the control keys, reassigning keycodes using `xmodmap` will not be possible for OP's problem.

To *solve* OP's problem, one would have to have a way to tell the operating system to (essentially) refuse to deliver separate events for <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> — but Linux and X do not work that way.  Limiting the scope to a particular application (xterm) or set of applications (Gtk-based programs), one might address those separately.  But a solution which applies system-wide does not seem doable.

Comment: The user can use xev to determine what events are being triggered by key presses

Comment: I accept this as the answer which basically says that it is not possible which imo is a valid answer.

Comment: This is disappointing :(